# @JsonTypeInfo has no effect

Tags: java, jackson

Using these dependencies

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.8"
compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13"
```

And then have an abstract class which has `@JsonTypeInfo`

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class", visible=true)
public abstract class Event {
...
}
```

However when I serialize a concrete sub-class there is no `@class` property in the output

A concrete subclass

```
public class SpecificEvent extends GatewayEvent {
    private String id;
    ...
}
```

And code to serialize it.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new FileWriter(new File("build/event.json")), new SpecificEvent("eventId"));
```

However I find that generated json does not contain a property @class and so the de-serialization also fails.

The generated json is something like.

```
{
  "id": "eventId"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing annotations and mapper from very different versions of jackson v1 from codehaus and v2 from fasterxml. Dependencies for using current version of Jackson (recommended) would be:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.8
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.8
```

(`jackson-annotations` probably not explicitly needed as `jackson-databind` depends on it).

Or if you absolutely must use the older version of Jackson:

```
org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13
```

I tried your `@JsonTypeInfo` with jackson 2.8.8 and I got (`JacksonBinding` is the package where my test class is):

```
{
  "@class" : "JacksonBinding.SpecificEvent",
  "id" : "eventId"
}
```

Which seems to be what you expect

Comment: A follow-up question though, The serialization was successfull. But de-serializing the generated file results in - `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "@class"`

Comment: You have specified `visible=true` in your `@JsonTypeInfo` and Jackson is trying to find a field named `@class` inside your Java class. In your case you should leave `visible=false` (default) value. This way Jackson will use it to infer the type and then remove it before deserializing.